# How do I access the data in Java objects returned by User.getAddresses() and User.getPhones()?

Tags: java, api

In [com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/model/User.html), many methods, such as `getAddresses()` and `getPhones()`, return a Java object that I can’t figure out what to do with.

Using `toString()`, I can see that the data I want is in the object (and looks like a list of HashMaps), but I can’t figure out how to convert it to a form that I can access, such as a list or array of `UserAddress` or `UserPhone`?

I’d also like to know how to build such objects so I can update users (although I suppose it’s likely that the answer to the first part of my question may make how to build them obvious)?

I have been able to update others things that don’t involve such objects, so I don’t need help with reading and updating in general, but I’ve struggling with these object for a couple of days now and can’t figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Directoy API uses JSON for communication. The Java client library used to communicate with the API parses and serializes the JSON to and from Java objects for easier usage in code. Have a look here for an idea of how it works: https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON

The problem with the current version of the library is that it doesn't serialize all the fields in the `User` class to usable objects. Instead maps, or list of maps, are used for complex fields. For example the `phones` field should be turned into a list of `UserPhone` objects, but instead becomes a list of maps. The only field that is being properly serialized is the `name` field, being a `UserName` object.

One way to manually turn the maps into the correct object is to use a json parser like Gson and parse the maps. Like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

ArrayList phones = (ArrayList) user.getPhones();
for (Object phone : phones) {
    UserPhone userPhone = gson.fromJson(phone.toString(), UserPhone.class);
    System.out.println(userPhone.getType() + "=" + userPhone.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe those methods return a collection, in which case you'll probably want to access the items they contain via their iterator. Something like this should work:

```
ListIterator addresses = user.getAddresses().iterator();

while(addresses.hasNext()) {
    Address address = addresses.next();
    // do something with the address
}
```

If you're not familiar with the Iterator object, this article might help: [How to use Iterator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)

Comment: I would suggest the foreach loop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but User.getAddresses() and User.getPhones() do not have iterator methods, so neither of the answers proposed here will work.

"`ListIterator addresses = user.getAddresses().iterator();`" gets the compiler error “The method iterator() is undefined for the type Object”.

"`for (UserAddress addr : user.getAddresses())`" gets the compiler error “Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable”.

I finally found a way to get the job done, though.  The follow codes actually works, even though it's difficult to believe this is the way I'm "supposed to" do it.

```
ArrayList<ArrayMap<String,String>> phones = (ArrayList<ArrayMap<String,String>>)user.getPhones();
for (ArrayMap<String,String> phone : phones)
    System.out.println(phone.get("type") + "=" + phone.get("value"));
```

It’d be nice to get the data into an instance of UserPhone, but I can’t figure out how to do that (other than doing a get & UserPhone.setXxxx for every possible keyword).

I was able to update a phone number by passing User.setPhones() an `ArrayList<UserPhone>` that I built from scratch.